# Prediction of a partial input

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

In the context of supervised machine learning, is there a way to make a prediction of a partial input (i.e., some features are unknown) in general? If not, are there models that support this feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All models are predictions from partial variable sets. We choose what we know of and have sufficiently complete variables for and build the best model we are able to build.

You have a couple of options:

1. Use only variables which are complete across training and test, even if that means just a few variables and do the best you can.
2. Do some masterful imputation and accept the consequences on the model (it will water down the results).
3. Use all the complete and easily imputable numerical variables plus any categorical variables with our without missing values and create a category "missing" or something like that, which becomes a slop column during one-hot.

You can do some research on `Binary Flags` to see how this might be accomplished. It has been very useful for me, particularly in regressions where the coefficients for each category are independent.